# very weird - addressing element

Tags: jquery, function

I have a crazy problem, which I can't explain:

```
function removeEntry(what) {    
    var what1 = '#ID'+what;
    //var what1 = '#ID33';
    $(what1).slideToggle();
    alert('..'+what1+'..');
}
```

It does NOT work like that, weirdly. The problem is not with my target element because if I activate the third line and comment out the second, it works.
I have looked at "what" and "what1" a thousand times with alert and in the console, it is correctly being handed over to the function, is always available and without spaces or whatever.

I cannot explain it and am going nuts here about a simple thing like that.

Thanks for any insight or experiences with odd behavior like that.

Comment: Please post a complete code example. Also, a jsFiddle.net example reproducing the issue is often helpful.

Comment: please specify the value you are populating in "what" variable

Comment: Try using '#ID'+what.toString()

Comment: what is always a series of numbers like 33 or 100056. I tried the toString method too.

Comment: it is working, there has to be some other thing wrong http://jsfiddle.net/x4jsfuar/12/ this is your code in a fiddle

Comment: Can you add this line after the first one in your function: `console.log($(what1))` and tell me if you see the element?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building it as a jQuery object directly from the number you're passing in?

Something like:

```
function removeEntry(what) {
    var what1 = $('[id="ID'+what+'"]');
    what1.slideToggle();
    console.log(what1[0]); //this returns the element
}
```

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. Thank you. I hope, this solves the problem. I still have my previous comment (that I couldn't post) in the cache so here goes: "I also would expect it to work. Simple thing after all. What I don't get: what1 is the same in both cases: "#ID33"... Or whatever I pass in... I figured it can't be anything in its vicinity, since the one works, the other not. A click on some other element calls the function and passes the value..."

Comment: Why should `$('[id="ID'+what+'"]')` work differently than `$('#ID'+what)`?

Comment: Good question @Oriol. My intuition says jQuery might treat a string differently than an object built from a selector directly. After looking around though, I can't seem to find anything that would confirm this. It would seem that OP needs to share more code before an actual working solution could be reached.